# How to report security issues to Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios

My colleague and I found another screen bypass bug in iOS 7 installed on iPhone 5 Black. How do we report this to Apple?

Comment: Bug Reporter (https://bugreport.apple.com) or Apple's Product Security page (https://ssl.apple.com/uk/support/security/) are probably good places to start.

Comment: The question for which this is marked as duplicate deals only with bugs and feedback. On the security front, Apple has a published mechanism to report issues. I'd like to have this question reopened so that I can post the appropriate answer for it.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of iOS 7 - iOS 7.0.2? Please edit the question to add the iOS 7 version that you have on the iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Apple Product Security page](https://ssl.apple.com/support/security/) states:

> To report security issues that affect Apple products, please contact: **product-security@apple.com**
>   ...
>   **PGP key information**
>   You can use [Apple's Product Security PGP key](https://www.apple.com/support/security/pgp/) to encrypt sensitive information sent via e-mail. The e-mail address is used to monitor for potential product security issues. Because we focus our response efforts to have the greatest impact across Apple's product line, we generally will not respond to the e-mail messages unless further information is needed for a security issue.

Comment: thanks for very useful reply. Did you guys also tried to replicate the issue. Some one is again and again editing my question and deleting the procedure to replicate the issue :(

Comment: I deleted the steps to replicate the issue because: a) it's not relevant to the question; b) having it out here is not going to be helpful and it's better not to publicize security issues

Answer (score 2):

Login to Apple Bug Reporter

http://bugreport.apple.com/‎

An Apple ID is required to use this tool